# App is considered spammy. Only 4 spam reports out of 110.000 views

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, status, spam

So our app has been running for 3 days now. About 1300 "plays" have been made and each play (with a maximum of 3 per day) posts an update to the users stream (if they allowed this). 
This message is basically the usual "I've played this game and got this score".

In total all of these updates have been viewed 110.000 times by Facebook users, of which only 4 people reported it as "spam".
Though the "Negative feedback" section of our app's stats indicates that our app is considered to be "spammy" and that we are in immediate danger of being restricted.

Complete message: "Warning level red: your app is considered spammy and is in immediate danger of being restricted. Look at your Insights metrics to see what may have caused this."

Now, to me atleast, it doesn't seem a lot to get 4 spam reports per 100K views. Can I safely ignore this message or is this something to take action on? Even if I should take action, what can I do? I can't prevent people from considering the update "spam" and the user who posted it explicitly allowed us to do so.

Am I missing another statistic I should be looking at?

Comment: How many shares / blocks and hides do you have?